# How to construct dynamic SQL where condition against JSON column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017, json-query, json-value

I have a SQL table that stores data in Json format. I am using sample data below to understand the issue. Each document type has its own JSON structure.

```
DocumentID  DocumentTypeID  Status    JsonData  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1             2             Active    {"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar","States":"[OK]"}  
2             2             Active    {"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Smith","States":"[TX,NY]"}
3             3             Active    {"Make":"Ford","Model":"Focus","Year":"[2020]"}  
4             3             Active    {"Make":"Tesla","Model":"X","Year":"[2012,2015,2019]"}
```

then I have another JSON that needs to use in Where condition

```
@Condition =   '{"FirstName": "James",LastName:"Smith","States":[TX]}'
```

I will also have `DocumentTypeID` as parameter

So in normal sql if i hard-code the property names then SQL would look something like

```
 SELECT * FROM Documents d
 WHERE 
 d.DocumentTypeID = @DocumentTypeID AND
 JSON_VALUE(d.JsonData,'$.FirstName') = JSON_VALUE(@Condition,'$.FirstName') AND
 JSON_VALUE(d.JsonData,'$.LastName') = JSON_VALUE(@Condition,'$.LastName') AND
 JSON_QUERY(d.JsonData,'$.States') = JSON_QUERY(@Condition,'$.States') -- This line is wrong. I have 
                                                                       -- to check if one array is  
                                                                       -- subset of another array
```

**Given**
The property names in `JsonData` column and `Condition` will exactly match for a given DocumentTypeID.

I already have another SQL table that stores DocumentType and its Properties. If it helps, I can store json path for each property that can be used in above query to dynamically construct where condition

```
DocumentTypeID      PropertyName             JsonPath         DataType
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2                    FirstName                $.FirstName       String
2                    LastName                 $.LastName        String
2                    States                   $.States          Array
3                    Make                     $.Make            String
3                    Model                    $.Model           String
3                    Year                     $.Year            Array
```

**ISSUE**
For each document type the @condition will have different JSON structure. How do i construct dynamic where condition? Is this even possible in SQL?

I am using C#.NET so i was thinking of constructing SQL query in C# and just execute SQL Query. But before i go that route i want to check if its possible to do this in TSQL

Comment: Do you have to pass the condition in as Json, or can you use standard parameters? I'm asking because the condition as Json might be a security hazard (SQL injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, JSON support was only added to SQL Server in 2016 version, and still have room for improvement. Working with JSON data that contains arrays is quite cumbersome, involving `OPENJSON` to get the data, and another `OPENJSON` to get the array data.
An SQL based solution to this is possible - but a I wrote - cumbersome.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```sql
DECLARE @Documents AS TABLE (
    [DocumentID] int, 
    [DocumentTypeID] int, 
    [Status] varchar(6), 
    [JsonData] varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @Documents ([DocumentID], [DocumentTypeID], [Status], [JsonData]) VALUES
(1, 2, 'Active', '{"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar","States":["OK"]}'),
(2, 2, 'Active', '{"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Smith","States":["TX","NY"]}'),
(2, 2, 'Active', '{"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Smith","States":["OK", "NY"]}'),
(2, 2, 'Active', '{"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Smith","States":["OH", "OK"]}'),
(3, 3, 'Active', '{"Make":"Ford","Model":"Focus","Year":[2020]}'),
(4, 3, 'Active', '{"Make":"Tesla","Model":"X","Year":[2012,2015,2019]}');
```

Note I've added a couple of rows to the sample data, to verify the condition is working properly.
Also, as a side Note - some of the JSON data in the question was improperly formatted - I've had to fix that.

Then, declare the search parameters (*Note: I still think sending a JSON string as a search condition is potentially **risky***):

```sql
DECLARE @DocumentTypeID int = 2,
        @Condition varchar(100) = '{"FirstName": "James","LastName":"Smith","States":["TX", "OH"]}';
```

(Note: I've added another state - again to make sure the condition works as it should.)

Then, I've used a common table expression with `openjson` and `cross apply` to convert the json condition to tabular data, and joined that cte to the table:

```sql
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT FirstName, LastName, [State]
FROM OPENJSON(@Condition)
    WITH (
        FirstName varchar(10) '$.FirstName',
        LastName varchar(10) '$.LastName',
        States nvarchar(max) '$.States' AS JSON
    ) 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(States)
    WITH (
        [State] varchar(2) '$'
    )
)

SELECT [DocumentID], [DocumentTypeID], [Status], [JsonData]
FROM @Documents 
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON([JsonData])
    WITH(
        -- Since we already have to use OPENJSON, no point of also using JSON_VALUE...
        FirstName varchar(10) '$.FirstName',
        LastName varchar(10) '$.LastName',
        States nvarchar(max) '$.States' AS JSON
    ) As JD
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(States)
    WITH(
        [State] varchar(2) '$'
    ) As JDS
JOIN CTE 
    ON JD.FirstName = CTE.FirstName
    AND JD.LastName = CTE.LastName
    AND JDS.[State] = CTE.[State]
WHERE DocumentTypeID = @DocumentTypeID
```

Results:

```
DocumentID  DocumentTypeID  Status  JsonData
2           2               Active  {"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Smith","States":["TX","NY"]}
2           2               Active  {"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Smith","States":["OH", "OK"]}
```